# How to prevent Android's DialogFragment title from messing up my layout?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am using a `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` to ask myself for some credentials.
The fragment is instantiated like this:

```
DialogFragment cf = CredentialDialogFrag.newInstance();
cf.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppTheme_TitleDialog);
cf.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "credentialDialog");
```

Whenever I set a title, the layout gets messed up:

[image]

Looking fine though if I don't use a title for my dialog:

[image]

**How can I prevent the title from expanding the width of my dialog? And why is this even happening?**
I could not find the corresponding style elements while reading through the predefined XML files.
I've also tried to create my own `windowTitleStyle`, which did not work out for me. I was able to change text color, font but unable to set the width of the title.

Layout xml (nothing too fancy):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragCredential"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragments.CredentialDialogFrag">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/til_login"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/input_cred_login"
                android:hint="@string/hint_cred_login" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/til_pass"
            android:layout_below="@+id/til_login"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/input_cred_pass"
                android:hint="@string/hint_cred_pass" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel"
            android:id="@+id/button_cred_cancel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/til_pass"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@android:string/ok"
            android:id="@+id/button_cred_ok"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_cred_cancel"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/til_pass"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/til_pass" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Dialog style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.TitleDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: If you are worried about the title length, which might be the cause of layout distortion, why don't you shorten it to use less space?

Comment: set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in `RelativeLayout` and also for `TextInputEditText` and `TextInputLayout`

Comment: Instead of using default title. Add TextView in you layout itself with larger textSize and show as title text. that's it. :-) you can customize it however you want.

Comment: I agree with Er.KaushikKajavadara... I use to set android:windowNoTitle to TRUE and manually add a textview as title... This way, I can easily customize/styling the TextView... It will be much easier than try to customize the default Title.

Comment: I don't think the title length is the culprit - it's much shorter than the overall layout? I might go with adding my own TextView and styling it according to my own needs. It's just... curiosity as to why the title behaves like this?